# The iOS Developer University Program

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I'm looking at the iOS Developer University Program, and wondering about how you share application with each other. It says that you can post them to a private website for presentation and grading purposes. What does that mean? Can I post it to a private website, so other people can download it and install it?

Anyone who can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i'm gonna try my luck here. I haven't heard of the University Program but, if you can compile on device, you can create .ipa files and simply share them. As if you wanted to put them on your own private store. (Which is what you're asking).

If the above is correct, then follow theses steps i've copied from a previous post of mine ; also, if you need more information about this process, make sure to ask in a comment :)

I work in a company that releases on a private store too, and it works in a very similar way. The only difference is, Apple does not check the app and it takes 1 minute to upload it, not 2 weeks.

How it works :

- Generate the ipa for entreprise distribution (with the correct
  provisioning profiles)
- Upload the ipa wherever you want, if you need
  something beautiful, you could make an app that lists your IPA (your
  store ^^) with information about it, and a link to download it (look
  below)
- Upload the .plist file and make it so the url in the url field
  is the .ipa that you uploaded on step 1.
- Create a basic HTML page with this line where you want it : Users can now clic it and download
  ;)

  ```
  *<*a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=YOUR-UPLOADED-PLIST-FILE.plist">Clic here ;-)</a>
  ```

(I had to add two ** at the start otherwise SO would show it as a link.)

Comment: Don't I need the enterprise distribution license to generate the ipa as eneterprise?

Comment: And can I make my app available for download and installation by just refer to the .ipa-file in a link like you did, without using Appstore?

Comment: I think you only need the 99$/y subscription, and you don't need the appstore that's for sure. Generating the ipa also creates a .plist, and you need both the .plist and the .ipa. Then simply create a  web link that points to the plist, the plist itself points to where you stored the ipa, and you're good to go.

Comment: So people who clicks on this link, can download and install my app without using appstore and Itunes?

Comment: Without waiting 3weeks for Apples approval? :)

Comment: But you need a subscription as an apple developer. And if you want it you could even publish your app on your own store. There are many other stores that aren't the apple store. Usually companies have their own if they publish their apps to a very specific group of users (clients).

Comment: Yes, I know. But I can do like you said by make a link that refers to my .IPA-file, and then people can download and install my app without waiting 3weeks for apples approval?

Comment: Nope, you are the approval. But you're not visible on the app store of course.
And if you wanna make it look better, you could make the webpage look like a store. And store the link i gave you in the "download" button.

The link has to be clicked from a device though

Comment: Apple is not involved whatsoever in the process i've described. Their only link is you being a developer and being allowed to create apps. What you do with it on your own store is none of their business

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have experience in developing apps with Vmware with mac osx as os?

Comment: That's really a serate topic but with a computer that has enough resources, it works like a charm. At least for me. I gave it 8Gb of ram (out of the 16 my machine has), and half my CPU (high end i7). This allows me to alt tab freely between the VM and my main OS, and both are running smoothly. Even when games are running on the main OS.

Comment: Does this work without the Iphone being jailbreaked?

Comment: I wouldn't know, i've never had a jailbroken phone :\

Comment: But does it work on an Iphone that is NOT jailbroken? :)

Comment: But does it work on an Iphone that is NOT jailbroken?

Comment: Well, yeah, of course. If I say it works and that i've never had a jailbroken phone, you could easily guess that it works on phones that are not jailbroken...